# How to navigate to a xaml page from class

Tags: c#, class, windows-phone-8, navigationservice

In my application, I have a class Chronometer which use a dispatcherTimer and Tick method. Each second, a variable decrease.

I would like that when the value of the variable is 0, a new xaml page is load.

I try to use `NavigationService` but this method work only in a xaml.cs file.

My xaml page which is visible when the variable decrease is : WordPage.xaml
The xaml page that i want to display is : FinalPage.xaml

Can you realize what I want? Please help me

EDIT :

My constructor of my class is :

```
public Chrono(DispatcherTimer newTimer, TextBlock chrono, TextBlock NumEquip, P1 page1)
    {
     //Part effaced
     m_page1 = page1;
    }
```

and the instanciation of the object Chrono is :

```
MonChrono = new Chrono(newTimer, this.TimeLabel,  this);
```

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: I haven't got my code on me, I post it this evening

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an instance of [NavigationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.aspx), that's the main problem. But you could possibly pass your page object as a parameter and access its `NavigationService.Property`

```
public void NavigateToPage(YouPageClass page)
{
    page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/PageToNavigateTo.xaml",
        UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

Sample project: http://www.abouchleih.com/wp-content/uploads/TestNavigationFromClass.zip

**Edit:**
I found a better solution. Don't pass the page object, bette pass it's NavigationService-Property, now you can simply call the same method from multiple pages.

Method in your class:

```
public static void Nav(NavigationService s, Uri destination)
{
    s.Navigate(destination);
}
```

Call from a page:

```
private void button_navigateTo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavService.Nav(this.NavigationService, new Uri("/PageToNavigateTo.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I try your solution, an error appear : NullReferencementExption. Are you sure that you code is good?

Comment: It worked for me. Are you sure you are passing an object != null? The method was located in a class "NavService". I called the method in the page I want the object from (YourPageClass). And it worked

Comment: Added link to sample project in the answer.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try this. I edit my first post to show what i try.

Comment: Nice to hear, but I found a better solution. Don't pass the page object, bette pass it's NavigationService-Property, now you can simply call the same method from multiple pages. Check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Use RootFrame in App.xaml

```
(App.Current as App).RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```