# NullReferenceException when navigate from Class1.cs to Page1.xaml in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, nullreferenceexception

I need to navigate to a Page1.xaml from a Class1.cs.

I tried this way on MainPage.cs

```
public void test()
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

And access it in Class1.cs:

```
...
MainPage window = new MainPage();
window.test();
....
```

But I get:

```
"[System.NullReferenceException]
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
instance of an object."
```

in NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Already read this: [How to navigate to a xaml page from class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422310/how-to-navigate-to-a-xaml-page-from-class), but didn't work.

Any help how can I do this?

PS: Class1.cs and Page1.cs has different namespaces, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to instantiate a page this way. Instead, you can use the `Navigate` method exposed by the `PhoneApplicationFrame`:

```
((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```